# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, flutter, crash

getting this crash in the play store under pre-launch report details of my bundle file

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newversity.android/com.newversity.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-_ZTAu_rK0htQZxK8_AK-wQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.newversity.android-LvjaRggzo2wdCnt195uXdg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.newversity.android-LvjaRggzo2wdCnt195uXdg==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.newversity.android-LvjaRggzo2wdCnt195uXdg==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.newversity.android-LvjaRggzo2wdCnt195uXdg==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-_ZTAu_rK0htQZxK8_AK-wQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.newversity.android-LvjaRggzo2wdCnt195uXdg==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-_ZTAu_rK0htQZxK8_AK-wQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.newversity.android-LvjaRggzo2wdCnt195uXdg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.newversity.android-LvjaRggzo2wdCnt195uXdg==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.newversity.android-LvjaRggzo2wdCnt195uXdg==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.newversity.android-LvjaRggzo2wdCnt195uXdg==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"

not able to reproduce this crash in my logs while running the app in debug build

Comment: Any update? I have the exact same case.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file

*android/app/build.gradle*

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }

}
```